# How to make the local storage item publicly shared over a network?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is this possible?
A local storage Item should be accessible from any computer over the network( From the same Google chrome extension which was previously set.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to achieve something like a sync behavior but it won't be possible to achieve this by accessing the local storage object from another computer because you can't do that.

You will have to save the data to a remote sync server where your extension will get its data from. It will than save the data (sync) to the same remote server when it is edited.